# Why do function return different value acording to capacity

Tags: c, string

I was doing research about the `strlen()`function in C and I saw a function and this function return diffirent value. If capacity of array is full, return incorrect result. If capacity of array is not full, return true result.
I am asking What is the reason?
Thanks too much all Readers.
That is function

```
int myStrlen(char *s)
{
    char *start;
    start = s;
    while (*s != 0)
    {
        ++s;
    }
    return s - start;
}
```

and main

```
int main()
{
    char x[4] = "What";
    printf("%d\n", myStrlen(x));
    return 0;

}//Output: 21
```

other main

```
int main()
{
    char x[5] = "What";
    printf("%d\n", myStrlen(x));
    return 0;

}//Output: 4
```

Comment: C does not support _methods_, only _functions_.

Comment: And use a debugger to see what happens. Hint: your first `main` invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: If your char buffer has room for only 4 characters, then where is the null character?  You've filled it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With this function

```
int main()
{
    char x[4] = "What";
    printf("%d\n", myStrlen(x));
    return 0;

}//Output: 21
```

there's no null-terminator in `x`. So it's [*undefined*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as `myStrlen()` loops over it looking for the null-terminator and any result is possible.

The assignment itself is valid and first four bytes of the string literal `"What"` is copied into `x`. But the array `x` can't be used as a C-string.

Comment: Thank you very much.Your link and explanation are very helpful for me.@l3x

Comment: Glad it helped. In general, if you are *copying* (like in your code) a string literal, then it's a good idea to *not* explicitly specify the size at all, such as `char str[] = "Hello";`. Here, compiler will allocate the necessary size for `str` and you wouldn't need to worry about it in case you decide to change the string literal. If you had `char s[5]="what";` then it has correct size. But later, if you change the string literal to `"What?"` then you also have to change the length (which is often forgetten and cause problems). By not specifying the size, it's easier to avoid such mistakes.

Answer (score 6):

The string `"What"` is of type `char[5]` due to the trailing null byte. A definition with `char[4]` truncates the string and shaves off the null byte.

Since in that case the null terminator is missing, `myStrlen` invokes undefined behavior.

Just use

```
char str[] = "What";
```

without any explicit array length in real code.

---

And, as @Olaf said in a comment to your question: **C does not have methods but *functions*!**
Methods are available in C++, where they are an alias for virtual functions, and in Java (which I don't have a clue about).

Mr Stroustroup says the following on methods in C++ in his book "The C++ Programming Language 4<sup>th</sup> Edition," Chapter 20.3.2:

> A  virtual  member  function  is  sometimes  called a  method.

Comment: It is very common to refer to all member functions as methods in OO languages, C++ being an exception. And then it reiterates on this with virtual methods and static methods. I don't think that it is very sensible to point at these differences as there is no standard nomenclature across languages, only certain communities use different names for the same concepts. This can get very confusing if you are used to nomenclature of one language community and get into another...

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek Every language has different terms. A string in C is something completely different in other OO languages (hope that's OK as an analogy). A C++ function is something different as opposed to a Java function. Using the term "method" in C++ is misleading as it's a **virtual** member function and is common enough we can call it convention (not standard but convention). My advice to beginners: learn the terms, stick to conventions, and bear in mind C++ differs inherently and massively from Java.

Comment: I love the comparisons you did. I actually think that whenever you say "string", everyone has an idea of what you're speaking about, be it an assembly, C, C++, Java, ... programmer or even DBA. I doubt that you can say the same about "member function" even when it comes only to OOP communities. However, I agree with the fact that a person should use proper terms as calling 'function' a 'method' is completely off.

Answer (score 2):

In C (and C++), strings are terminated with a binary 0, or '\0'. Your declaration is too short for that, so you produced an unterminated string, which will lead to all kind of errors and crashes, depending on what you do with it.

First effect is that the strlen function keeps counting through memory behind that string, until it happens to find a 0; that could be at 21, at 134, or ending with a crash - you are trespassing memory that doesn't belong to the program, and sooner or later it will produce problems.

You need to declare that string as [5], to have space for the terminating '\0'.

Comment: Don't confuse declaration and definition. An array declaration does not need a size specifier at all.